# Regexp issue involving reverse polish calculator

Tags: ruby, regex, calculator, rpn

I'm trying to use a regular expression to solve a reverse polish calculator problem, but I'm having issues with converting the mathematical expressions into conventional form.

I wrote:

```
puts '35 29 1 - 5 + *'.gsub(/(\d*) (\d*) (\W)/, '(\1\3\2)')
```

which prints:

```
35 (29-1)(+5) *
```

expected

```
(35*((29-1)+5))
```

but I'm getting a different result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the `*` come from?

Comment: You cannot make it in a single run of gsub because the following matches will rely on the previous replacement unless you do a recursive call.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant to put '35 29 1 - 5 + *'. And I should be using sub, not gsub, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you meant you tried

```
puts '35 29 1 - 5 + *'.gsub(/(\d*) (\d*) (\W)/, '(\1\3\2)')
                    ^           ^
```

Anyway, you have to use the quantifier `+` instead of `*`, since otherwise you will match an empty string for `\d*` as one of your captures, hence the `(+5)`:

```
/(\d+) (\d+) (\W)/
```

I would further extend/constrain the expression to something like:

```
/([\d+*\/()-]+)\s+([\d+*\/()-]+)\s+([+*\/-])/
 |             |  |             |   |
 |             |  |             |   Valid operators, +, -, *, and /.
 |             |  |             |   
 |             |  |             Whitespace.
 |             |  |                 
 |             |  Arbitrary atom, e.g. "35", "(29-1)", "((29-1)+5)".
 |             |                    
 |             Whitepsace.                  
 |
 Arbitrary atom, e.g. "35", "(29-1)", "((29-1)+5)".
```

...and instead of using `gsub`, use `sub` in a `while` loop that quits when it detects that no more substitutions can be made.  This is very important because otherwise, you will violate the order of operations.  For example, take a look at [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/9mEd9LGfeV).  You can see that by using `gsub`, you might potentially replace the second triad of atoms, "5 + *", when really a second iteration should substitute an "earlier" triad *after* substituting the first triad!

**WARNING:** The `-` (minus) character must appear *first* or *last* in a character class, since otherwise it will specify a range!  (Thanks to @JoshuaCheek.)

Comment: Awesome answer! But minus sign can also appear first.